# Excel export to Word (VBA): problem with loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, ms-word

I'm having difficulties with the following:

I want to export data from an Excel Sheet to a Word document. The code for that works, but the problem is that specific blocks of code need to be repeated. And that's were it goes wrong.

This is an extract of the code:

```
        Voortgang:



If Controle1 = True Then
            GoTo OpmaakKatern2


    End If
    If Controle2 = True Then
        GoTo OpmaakKatern3

    End If







OpmaakKatern1:
                If Datum1 = Empty Then
                        Controle1 = False
                        GoTo Eindsorteren
                Else:
                    Controle1 = True
                End If
                .TypeParagraph  'Hier start katern1
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Size = 12
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Underline = True
                .TypeText Text:=Katern1     'Hier staat de naam van de katern
                .Font.Bold = False
                .Font.Underline = False
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Font.Underline = True
                .TypeText Text:="Datum:"    'Hier komt de gesorteerde datum, in te lezen als variabele
                .Font.Underline = False
                .TypeText Text:=" " & Datum1   'Hier komt de gesorteerde datum, in te lezen als variabele (aanhalingstekens verwijderen voor de variabele)
                .TypeParagraph
                .Font.Underline = True
                .TypeText Text:="Gerealiseerde leerplandoelstellingen:"
                .Font.Underline = False
                If Katern1 = "Een nieuwe start" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_EenNieuweStart
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Alles heeft zijn tijd" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_AllesHeeftZijnTijd
                ElseIf Katern1 = "De wereld aan je voeten" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_DeWereldAanJeVoeten
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Een levend boek" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_EenLevendBoek
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Drempels" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Drempels
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Kerstmis" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Kerstmis
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Confituur of choco" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_ConfituurOfChoco
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Hoe groot is de hemel?" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_HoeGrootIsDeHemel
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Ongelovige Thomas" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_OngelovigeThomas
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Feesten" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Feesten
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Er is er één jarig!" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_ErIsErEénJarig
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Eén van hart" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_EénVanHart
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Ervoor gaan" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_ErvoorGaan
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Groen gras" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_GroenGras
                ElseIf Katern1 = "RELatie" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_RELatie
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Vele plaatjes" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_VelePlaatjes
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Iedereen fan" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_IedereenFan
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Schattenjacht" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Schattenjacht
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Lichtbakens" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_Lichtbakens
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Rijke Luis" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_RijkeLuis
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Hemel op aarde" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_HemelOpAarde
                ElseIf Katern1 = "Op bezoek" Then
                    GoTo Invulling_OpBezoek
                End If
```

And this is an example of an Invulling_-block:

```
Invulling_ErIsErEénJarig:


                        If Worksheets("Theo").Rij12_4.Value = True Then
                            .TypeParagraph
                            .TypeText Text:=Rij12
                        End If
                        If Worksheets("Theo").Rij13_4.Value = True Then
                            .TypeParagraph
                            .TypeText Text:=Rij13
                        End If
                        If Worksheets("Theo").Rij14_4.Value = True Then
                            .TypeParagraph
                            .TypeText Text:=Rij14
                        End If
                        If Worksheets("Theo").Rij15_3.Value = True Then
                            .TypeParagraph
                            .TypeText Text:=Rij15
                        End If
                        If Worksheets("Theo").Rij20_6.Value = True Then
                            .TypeParagraph
                            .TypeText Text:=Rij20
                        End If
                        If Worksheets("Theo").Rij22_5.Value = True Then
                            .TypeParagraph
                            .TypeText Text:=Rij22
                        End If
                        If Worksheets("Theo").Rij25_4.Value = True Then
                            .TypeParagraph
                            .TypeText Text:=Rij25
                        End If
                        If Worksheets("Theo").Rij28_4.Value = True Then
                            .TypeParagraph
                            .TypeText Text:=Rij28
                        End If
                        GoTo Voortgang
```

This is how it should work: 
First the blok 'OpmaakKatern1" is run. In this block, a certain bit of content is picked ip ("Invulling_..."), and at the end of these Invulling_-blocks, there is a GoTo command which sends the code up to a controller ("Voortgang:"), which should check which "OpmaakKatern.." has already been executed. 
But this doesn't work. It keeps repeating the second OpmaakKatern, instead of moving to the third OpmaakKatern.

Is there anyone who could help me on this one?

Thanks a lot!

Kind regards, 
Marc

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a line somewhere in the OpmaakKatern2 block setting Controle2 to True?

```
Controle2 = True
```